# Parse date when format is not constant c#

Tags: c#, date

normally i parse date like this way

```
DateTime.Parse()
DateTime.ParseExact()
```

i am in situation where user run exe and pass date as argument. so user can give date with various format like

```
dd/MM/yyyy
MM/dd/yyyy
dd-MM-yyyy
MM-dd-yyyy
yyyyMMdd
```

so i have to parse that date. when date format is yyyyMMdd then i am parisng date like this way `DateTime.ParseExact(this.enddate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

so guide me what code i should write to parse date which work for any date format. thanks

Comment: dd/MM/yyyy, MM/dd/yyyy - how do you know which format is date 01/02/2013?

Comment: i believe this is a well defined problem, unless you dictate the pattern, there is 80-20 chances of getting correct dates out of generic pattern, the 20 being dates like 10-12-2013 i.e. where month number and date is less than 12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend that you standardize on a single format. Otherwise you will run into ambiguous dates in cases where you have dates that can be parsed by different formats, but represent different dates in both
Ex:
dd-MM-yyyy
MM-dd-yyyy

Comment: I will give one more +1 if I can

Answer (score 1):

> what code i should write to parse date which work for any date format

As a technical answer, you can pass **multiple** formats to [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) via a string array containing all acceptable formats.

*Practically, though, the others have already pointed out that there is no way to tell the difference between months and days when the format isn't strictly enforced.*

One possible solution is to have the user pass the date in as three separate arguments, each flagged with some kind of indicator such as `/y2013 /m11 /d12` or maybe `y:2013 m:11 d:12`.  You can even mash them together like `/y2013/m11/d12`.  Then you can use Regular Expressions to parse out the parts, or even just plain old string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way to parse dates which work for ANY format. However, you can quite easily define your own format using [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), letting you convert more or less any format to a proper date, as long as you know the format ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

In every major website you enter the date using comboboxes for day/month/year
or some datetime widget. So I don't see a reason to use a textbox. If you really
need to, add a tooltip or a watermark with the predefined format and force the
user to it.